# While connecting with LinkedIn from my native application i have got one message what it means?

Tags: iphone

I have used LinkedIn in my Native iphone application and i have got the message below:I don't know what it means:The masage is"You have successfully authorised [AppName].Please return to your application and enter following security code to grant access: 61592 "  please help me what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Its an OpenAuth step. Without knowing what "used Linkedin in my native iPhone app" actual entails, all I can do is refer you here http://oauth.net/

Andrew

Comment: i have completed authentication step after that i have got this message to my iphone:"You have successfully authorised [AppName].Please return to your application and enter following security code to grant access: 61592 "

Comment: As I said - its part of oAuth. Open Auth on mobile devices (rather than web) is designed that it will return a code, that the user will enter into your application in order to complete the Authorization cycle. I have used solutions that read that pin number using jQuery and therefore allow the user to skip that step. I used this library (for twitter, but it includes an oAuth implementation and sample of reading back the pin) in a couple of apps. http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

Comment: i have already taken the source code from github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone but i have got message:"You have successfully authorised [AppName].Please return to your application and enter following security code to grant access: 61592 " while compile and run and i can't understand what i should do next.i mean from which place i should enter this security number for grant access.Do you know where should i enter this security number?

Comment: the oAuth code there uses jQuery to parse the page returned by twitter (different to the page returned by LinkedIn) to get the pin and use it. You will need to read the jQuery, look at the page that is being returned, and fix up the jQuery to properly fetch the pin. I seem to remember the jQuery was very simple - just using a class selector or something similar.

Comment: Do you have any sample code regarding LinkedIn post or any standard procedure for posting blog on wall.

Comment: sorry - I'm no linkedin expert. If you have your oauth sorted out, I'd ask a new question.